# reports in jasper grails

Tags: grails, jasper-reports

My controller action is

```
def jasper () {
      def emp = Employee.findAll()
    chain(controller:'jasper', action:'index', model:[data:emp],params:params)
}
```

and in my jrxml file i have following fields: *name, lastname, gender, phone*

I want to write a query that would have data only of name and lastname but with same jrxml file then my action would be

```
def jasper () {
      def emp = Employee.executeQuery("select a.name  a.lastname from Employee a ")
    chain(controller:'jasper', action:'index', model:[data:emp],params:params)
}
```

This do not print only name and lastname in my report rather gives *NoSuchMethodException*. How to do this?

Comment: Is first one query working fine? and did you print result executed from executeQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the second query result could be a replacement of the first since the structure of the result is completely different.

In the first case you will get a `List<Employee>`, while in the second case you get an `List<Object[]>`.

You could rework your Jasper report to expect `List<Object[]>` and use `select a.name, a.lastname, a.gender, a.phone from Employee a` for the first scenario. In this case, you could safeguard the report agains the possible null values so that the report works well with the second, more limited result set.